# Date-time picker is not working inside Javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

my date-time picker did'nt works when i put it inside javascript code but it works fine when its outside javascript. If anyone can solve this or can tell how can i access the date-time picker placed outside the javascript code in a similar way as below. In the code below I am dynamically adding the form elements based on the selection box selection event.

```js
function addToFilter(divName)
{
  var val= document.getElementById('filter').value;
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
  switch(val)
  {
    case 'mcus': 
      newdiv.innerHTML = "Multi company use case &nbsp: "+ 
        "<select id='mcuc_selection'>"+
        "<option value='select'>--select--</option><option value='ags'>AGS</option><option value='agl'>AGL</option><option value='nafn'>NAFN</option></select>"+ 
        "&nbsp;<img id='remove-icon' src='remove-icon.jpg' alt='remove'  onmouseover='' style='cursor: pointer;'>"+
        "<hr style='width:700px; margin-left:0px;'>";
      break;

    case 'oc': 
      newdiv.innerHTML = "Order Condition &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;: <select id='oc_selection'><option value='select'>--select--</option><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option><option value='5'>5</option><option value='6'>6</option><option value='7'>7</option></select> &nbsp;<img id='remove-icon' src='remove-icon.jpg' alt='remove'  onmouseover='' style='cursor: pointer;'><hr style='width:700px; margin-left:0px;'>";
      break;

    case 'ot': 
      newdiv.innerHTML = "Order Type &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;: <select id='oc_selection'><option value='select'>--select--</option><option value='shadow'>shadow</option><option value='customer'>customer</option></select> &nbsp;<img id='remove-icon' src='remove-icon.jpg' alt='remove'  onmouseover='' style='cursor: pointer;'><hr style='width:700px; margin-left:0px;'>";
      break;

    case 'dt': 
      newdiv.innerHTML = "Date&Time&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:"+
        "<div id='startDate' class='input-append date'>"+
        "<label>Start Date&Time: </label>"+
        "<input type='text' style='width:200px; height:15%'></input>"+
        "<span class='add-on' style='height:26px'>"+
        "<i id='dateIcon1' data-time-icon='icon-time' data-date-icon='icon-calendar'></i>"+
        "</span>"+
        "</div>"+
        "<div id='endDate' class='input-append date' style='margin-left:400px; margin-top:-30px'>"+
        "<label>End Date&Time:&nbsp;</label>"+
        "<input type='text' style='width:200px; height:15%'></input>"+
        "<span class='add-on' style='height:26px'>"+
        "<i id='dateIcon1' data-time-icon='icon-time' data-date-icon='icon-calendar'></i>"+
        "</span>"+
        "</div>"+
        "&nbsp;<img id='remove-icon' src='remove-icon.jpg' alt='remove'  onmouseover='' style='cursor: pointer;'><hr style='width:700px; margin-left:0px;'>";
      break;

  }
  document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
}


$('#startDate').datetimepicker({
  format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss PP',
  language: 'en',
  pick12HourFormat: true
});
$('body').click(function (evt) {
  $(".startDate, .dropdown-menu").css("display","none");
}); 
$('#endDate').datetimepicker({
  format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss PP',
  language: 'en',
  pick12HourFormat: true
});
$('body').click(function (evt) {
  $(".endDate, .dropdown-menu").css("display","none");
});
```

Comment: It is because you are dynamically adding form elements, so you need to call datetimepicker dynamically everytime you push the elements in the view

Comment: Can, you be little broad on "How it could be done" ???

Comment: when your html is created successfully and you assign it to the outer div , then just call the function where you place the datetimepicker code

Comment: I am putting the jquery code inside a javascript function so that it could be called at the same time as the html code for the date-time picker. Though the javascript function is getting called but the date time picker is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can't have two elements with same ids, inside addToFilter function when you add datetime picker for startDate and endDate from the second row it will be duplicated, so it won't work in any way

Secondly, you need to call datetime picker when you pushed HTML element in the view

So your code will become

```
function addToFilter(divName)
{
  var val= document.getElementById('filter').value;
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
  switch(val)
  {
    case 'mcus': 
      newdiv.innerHTML = "Multi company use case &nbsp: "+ 
        "<select id='mcuc_selection'>"+
        "<option value='select'>--select--</option><option value='ags'>AGS</option><option value='agl'>AGL</option><option value='nafn'>NAFN</option></select>"+ 
        "&nbsp;<img id='remove-icon' src='remove-icon.jpg' alt='remove'  onmouseover='' style='cursor: pointer;'>"+
        "<hr style='width:700px; margin-left:0px;'>";
      break;

    case 'oc': 
      newdiv.innerHTML = "Order Condition &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;: <select id='oc_selection'><option value='select'>--select--</option><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option><option value='5'>5</option><option value='6'>6</option><option value='7'>7</option></select> &nbsp;<img id='remove-icon' src='remove-icon.jpg' alt='remove'  onmouseover='' style='cursor: pointer;'><hr style='width:700px; margin-left:0px;'>";
      break;

    case 'ot': 
      newdiv.innerHTML = "Order Type &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;: <select id='oc_selection'><option value='select'>--select--</option><option value='shadow'>shadow</option><option value='customer'>customer</option></select> &nbsp;<img id='remove-icon' src='remove-icon.jpg' alt='remove'  onmouseover='' style='cursor: pointer;'><hr style='width:700px; margin-left:0px;'>";
      break;

    case 'dt': 
      newdiv.innerHTML = "Date&Time&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:"+
        "<div class='startDatePicker input-append date'>"+
        "<label>Start Date&Time: </label>"+
        "<input type='text' style='width:200px; height:15%'></input>"+
        "<span class='add-on' style='height:26px'>"+
        "<i id='dateIcon1' data-time-icon='icon-time' data-date-icon='icon-calendar'></i>"+
        "</span>"+
        "</div>"+
        "<div class='endDatePicker input-append date' style='margin-left:400px; margin-top:-30px'>"+
        "<label>End Date&Time:&nbsp;</label>"+
        "<input type='text' style='width:200px; height:15%'></input>"+
        "<span class='add-on' style='height:26px'>"+
        "<i id='dateIcon1' data-time-icon='icon-time' data-date-icon='icon-calendar'></i>"+
        "</span>"+
        "</div>"+
        "&nbsp;<img id='remove-icon' src='remove-icon.jpg' alt='remove'  onmouseover='' style='cursor: pointer;'><hr style='width:700px; margin-left:0px;'>";
      break;

  }
  document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
  bindDatePickers($('#'+divName))
}

function bindDatePickers(element) {
    $($(element).find('.startDatePicker')).datetimepicker({
      format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss PP',
      language: 'en',
      pick12HourFormat: true
    });

    $($(element).find('.endDatePicker')).datetimepicker({
      format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss PP',
      language: 'en',
      pick12HourFormat: true
    });
}

$('body').click(function (evt) {
  $(".startDate, .dropdown-menu").css("display","none");
}); 
$('body').click(function (evt) {
  $(".endDate, .dropdown-menu").css("display","none");
});
```

Comment: No, it didn't worked for me. It displayes only the textbox the date-time picker menu is not getting opened.

Comment: @SidhantKushwaha: Would you create jsfiddle for this

Comment: jsfiddle is a webpage where you can paste your javascript, html and css code, and see result online, so you can create a small working example there, and there I can see what bug you are facing ... The reason behind creating this is that, I have read your code and given you answer on conceptual basis, I haven't run mine code... so I need a working platform where I can debug this. You can create fiddle here -> http://www.jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Hi, i added the required part in https://jsfiddle.net/fuu1v2t0/ . my html file is quite big so i cannot load whole of its content, and i didn't think its required. Also u need to import " jquery-1.3.2.min.js " .

Comment: @SidhantKushwaha: Okay looking into it

Comment: @SidhantKushwaha : see where I put cellDate function, in the fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/fuu1v2t0/2/ .. does it help you?

Comment: No, it won't helped me. The callDate function is getting called but the scripts inside is not working that's why the date-time menu to select data-time is not displaying.

Comment: @SidhantKushwaha : have you added any file for datetimepicker? would you show me which datepicker you are using?

Comment: Yes,a number of file but that should not be a problem as date-time is working file on the same page if i placed the content in switch case outside the javascript and the callDate content after removing the callDate function

Comment: Yes, the error in console is : Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function. I also udated the file i am using for bootstrap date time picker in css area https://jsfiddle.net/fuu1v2t0/4/ . If this is not working you are free to use any date-time picker in the format DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS PP.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function  ---- This error only occurs if your javascript doesn't find jquery and/or bootstrap datetimepicker files ... You need add all these files in head tag specifying all scripts

Comment: All these files are there but now also its working in your jsfiddle but not in my code.

Comment: @SidhantKushwaha see in left pane "External Resources" see that whether you have added all files that are there or not?, Also check your code is in <script></script> tags of head or not

Comment: All files are there, but i am editing a template which has a number of js files (about 25) imported and a number of css files (about 15) its order are creating a problem. Some are in the head section whereas some are placed after the footer section. if i jumble up these file the datepicker works but some page css are gone.

Comment: Thanks @Parag you really helped me a lot.